# Is there a simple way to prove the Four Colour Theorem?

Tags: proof-writing

The four colour theorem says that:

> Given any separation of a plane into contiguous regions, producing a figure called a map, no more than four colours are required to colour the map so that no two adjacent regions have the same colour.
>
> From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_colour_theorem

The theorem has been proved using computers. But I am wondering, is there a more simple proof than using computers to do it? I feel that using brute force to prove something is like the last resort. So, is there a simple proof of the Four Colour Theorem, or is it yet to be proved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A completely computer-free proof has yet to exist. However there are easy proofs for the five(and up) color theorems.

Answer (score 2):

no, there isn't. This has been proved using a computer which took hundreds of hours as you have to go through every proof separately.

Answer (score -2):

The four colour theorem was supposedly proved by 'Appel and Haken' by using a computer as a tool. They used the tool to supposedly go through every example possible. However there is no 'proof' that the proof actually happened and exists.  I guess it can be proved by hand but it would take you years.. So the answer is no there is no simple proof of the four colour theorem.

Comment: There have been formally verified proofs of 4CT.  Georges Gonthier created a proof verified by the coq proof assistant.  [Details here](http://www.ams.org/notices/200811/tx081101382p.pdf)

Comment: You wrote "However there is no 'proof' that the proof actually happened and exists". What do you mean by this? Details were published in Appel, Kenneth; Haken, Wolfgang (1989), Every Planar Map is Four-Colorable, Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society, ISBN 0-8218-5103-9