# Non- computational proof for Four Colour Theorem

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, fake-proofs, coloring, proof-theory

I was browsing a the internet to see if there was a non-computationally intensive proof for the four and sources consistently say that there is not.

Quora: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-proof-of-the-Four-Color-Theorem-that-does-not-involve-substantial-computation

Stack Exchange: [Is there a simple way to prove the Four Colour Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717551/is-there-a-simple-way-to-prove-the-four-colour-theorem)

However, I've come across a compelling proof that seems to do just that.  The gist is that it considers the worst case: fully connected graphs force you to use V different colours where V is the number of vertices. In order to prove the 4CT, they proved that the **maximum** graph (w.r.t number of nodes) that still maintains planarity has max 4 nodes (max four colours needed).  Therefore if you add an extra node to the graph, you could only connect it to 3 out of the 4 nodes from the previous graph while still maintaining planarity. This guarantees that there will always be a colour of the 4 that can be reused.

**QUESTION: is this a fake proof?**

Link: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2102948_A_Simple_Proof_of_the_Four-Color_Theorem

If it was valid I feel it would have been well known in academia by now, but the consensus is that the 4CT is yet to be proven in this way.

Comment: There are non-complete planar graphs with more than 4 nodes and chromatic number equal to 4. A new node may be added to such graphs so that it requires connection to more than three nodes and yet the resulting graph is still planar.  Your intuition that a simple proof of the four-color theorem that had been around for several years would be well known is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Any proof that talks about the "worst case" for something to hold should immediately be considered suspect. This is not to say that there are never correct proofs that involve a reduction to the worst case. However, at a minimum, all such proofs must:

- Describe exactly the quantity that the "worst case" is maximizing;
- Show that cases that are *not* "worst" can be reduced to worse cases, such that if you solve the worse cases, you solve the original cases as well.

Then, and only then, can a solution to the "worst case" be a general solution. (At that point, the argument becomes a form of proof by induction.)

---

In the case of the Four-Color Theorem, the problem is that complete graphs (or, more generally, graphs in which $k$ vertices are all connected to each other) are not necessarily a "worst case" for coloring. The [Mycielski graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian#Iterated_Mycielskians) form a sequence of graphs with ever-increasing chromatic number - they need more and more colors to be properly colored - but none of them even contain $3$ vertices all adjacent to each other.

More generally, random constructions can be used to find graphs which require $1000$ colors to properly color, but in which the shortest cycle has length $1000$ as well: so for any vertex, we can color just the vertices within $499$ steps just with $2$ colors by a greedy approach and not have to deal with *any* conflicts. This can be done for any value of $1000$.

Of course, the Four-Color Theorem says that none of these graphs which require more than $4$ colors can be planar. But the point is that excluding cliques (groups of vertices, all adjacent to each other) of size $5$ or more does not come close to excluding *all* configurations that require $5$ or more colors.